# NSString hasPrefix: vs hasSuffix: which is less expensive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

In my project I need to have a list of predefined prefix or suffix for string items, it can be either prefix or suffix, so that I can go through the items and check the prefix or suffix of each item, just wondering which is less expensive? It feels like `hasPrefix:` is less expensive but I don't have any reference to support this.

Thanks

Comment: When you use methods programmed by third developers, and they can improve performance and optimize for each version, you'd better using the better for your code coherence and readability. Using a language that lays on an interpreter for calling methods, IMO, comparing strings don't make a performance issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSString` is "toll-free bridged" to `CFStringRef`, so 
you can check the implementation in
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.19/CFString.c.

The relevant functions are `CFStringHasPrefix()` and `CFStringHasSuffix()`, which call
`CFStringFindWithOptionsAndLocale()` without or with the `kCFCompareBackwards` flag.

As I understand the code, this flag has no influence on the performance, only some loop variables are initialized differently.

(But the general "disclaimer" applies here as well: You should profile your application
and check if the prefix/suffix check is a performance bottleneck at all. 
If not, choose whatever is more logical or easier to maintain.)

Comment: Just as an FYI, I was looking for a faster method for getting NSString prefixes (faster than [NSString hasPrefix:prefix]).  I tried out CFStringHasPrefix() and found that it was 2-3 times faster than the NSString equivalent in my application.  I would guess that this might be true for all of the CFStringRef equivalents.